# Problem with LabelEncoder class of sklearn library in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataset of size 10 like this:

```py
Purchased
----------
Yes
Yes
No
Yes
No
...
```

I want to use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` to encode my data set using `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer`.
Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

#dataset:
dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values

y = np.reshape(y, (10, 1))

ct = ColumnTransformer([("labelEncoder", LabelEncoder(), [0])], "drop")
y = ct.fit_transform(y)
```

But when I run this code an error from`y = ct.fit_transform(y)` rises:

```py
TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```